# How to place a check on image on that means when image is clicked in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

How to place a check on image on that means when image is clicked in Flutter?

```
child: new Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.transparent,
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15))),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                              child: ClipRRect(
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
                                child: Image.network(
                                  state.photos[index].urls.small,
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          highlightColor: Colors.blue,
                          radius: 15,
                          // radius: 35.0,
                          onTap: () {
                          
                            Alignment.topRight;
                            Icon(Icons.check_box);
                                                   
                          },
                        );
                      },
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this out:

```
bool checked=false;

//...

Stack(
            children: [
              InkWell(
                onTap: ()=> setState(() {
                    checked=!checked;
                  }),

                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius:
                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
                  child: Image.network(
                    state.photos[index].urls.small,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Visibility(
                visible: checked,
                  child: Checkbox(

                    value: checked,
                    onChanged: (v)=>setState((){
                      checked=v;
                    }),
                  ),
              )
            ],
          ),
```

Comment: You're dealing with changing values, so you need to convert it to a StatefulWidget.